# MySQL exact path

Tags: mysql

I am using

```
whereis mysql
```

in my terminal to get exact location of my MySQL installation, but it's showing too many locations:

```
mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/bin/X11/mysql /usr/share/mysql /opt/lampp/bin/mysql /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

Does it mean that I have installed MySQL more than once?

Comment: [use `type` instead of `whereis`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22565) (and yes, it would appear that you have at least two installations of `mysql`)

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is all the directories called `mysql`, which are all part of the package you've installed.

If you're on a Debian-like system (including Ubuntu), you can do

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

which will give you a list of mysql-related packages installed.  To reconcile these results with those from `whereis`, you can find a list of files installed by a particular package, e.g.

```
dpkg -L mysql-server-5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use something like

```
which mysql
```

to find out location of mysql.

With that command you would get:

```
user@machine ~ $ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes but it's giving me too many paths and i need to figure out which MySQL is running at the moment.

Comment: whereis command would give you output like mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/lib64/mysql /usr/include/mysql /usr/sh
are/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.bz2 (it gives you all locations with mysql) but which should give you location of mysql executable (mysql that you are using) or maybe i'm wrong.